# Sticky Objects? PR2 Simulation, objects stick to gripper

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have troubles with gazebo models that stick to the PR2 gripper. The robot pushes objects with the gripper, not using the gripper for grasping but just to push. When the gripper is retracted, the objects that were pushed away are pulled back with the gripper again, as if there was glue between the gripper and the object.

Can this behavior be adjusted via the SurfaceParameters ?

Any other thoughts?

Thank you!

-tom

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1700/sticky-objects?-pr2-simulation,-objects-stick-to-gripper/) by [TomTUM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/245/tomtum/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can try and play around with the parameters, in general, reduce interpenetration by increasing stiffness (changing kp and kd), increasing maxVel or reducing minDepth for the gripper might help.  A large part of the reason might be because the trimesh-trimesh contact is generating bad collision points/joints, replacing gripper pads with simple box rectangles might help ([ticketed](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/568/make-simplified-collision-models-for-pr2)).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0